# Why is the azimuthal current density $j_\phi = \frac{Q}{T}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics

I am looking at the solution for one of the problems I had for homework. I have an infinite cable of linear charge density $-\lambda$ and an insulating concentric cylindrical shell around the cable. The cylinder starts rotating and, at the end, there is a magnetic field because of the rotating shell moving the charges in the insulator (This is my guess). To calculate this magnetic field, I am supposed to use Ampere's Law $\oint \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathrm{d} \mathbf{l} = \mu_0 I_{enc}$. So I need to calculate these current enclosed. The solution says that I have to use the azimuthal current density formula $j_\phi = Q/T$. Where does this formula come from?

Comment: I think, this is wrong. The current density is defined as charge per time and area unit: $j=I/A=Q/tA$ The definition of $j_\phi$ seems to be missing the area part, so by dimensional analysis it cannot be a current density but is rather a current.

Comment: I am slightly confused by the homework in general. The line charge is infinite? The cylinder is finite, I guess, as otherwise there is no "end" where the magnetic field can be. The insulator is neutral, so I do not see how its rotation should produce a magnetic field. Is it possible the the question was about the line charge being on the surface of the rotating cylinder? This definitively would produce a magnetic field as in a solenoid. It also would explain the choice of $j_\phi$ and the current would be related to the rotational period $T$ as $\propto \lambda/T$